# Integral of sine involving monimials

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Consider an integral

$$
s(n, h, a, b) := \int^h_{-h} x^n \sin(a \, x + b), \quad n \geq 0 \in \mathbb{N}.
$$

Do we have an analytical expression of $s$ interms of $n, h, a, b$?

Comment: You can express $s(n,h,a,b)$ in terms of $s(n-2,h,a,b)$ easily enough using integration by parts if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\sin(ax + b) = \sin(ax)\cos b + \cos(a x)\sin b$ and the symmetry of the integrand, this integral can be reduced to
$$
s(n,h,a,b) = \begin{cases}2a^{-n-1}\sin b\int_0^h u^n \cos u\,du & n \in 2\mathbb Z \\ 2a^{-n-1}\cos b\int_0^h u^n \sin u\, du & n\notin 2\mathbb Z\end{cases}
$$
Let's try to get rid of that annoying alternation of sine and cosine. We note that both $\sin b \cos u$ for even $n$ and $\cos b\sin u$ for odd $n$ can be expressed as $\mathrm{Im}[i^n e^{i b}]\mathrm{Re}[i^n e^{-i h}]$. We can then build $S$ up by starting with $\int_0^h e^{-iu}\,du$ and repeatedly integrating by parts. We get
$$
-i+ie^{-i h} = \int_0^h e^{-i u}\,du = h e^{-i h} +i\int_0^h u e^{-i u}\,du = h e^{-i u}+i\frac{h^2}{2}e^{-i h}-\int_0^h\frac{u^2}{2}e^{-i u}\, du = \,...
$$
Continuing this process until we reach $n$, we get
$$
-i + i e^{-i h} = \sum_{k = 1}^n i^{k-1}\frac{h^k}{k!}e^{-i h}+\frac{i^n}{n!}\int_0^h u^n e^{-i u}du \\\Longrightarrow \frac{i^n}{n!}\int_0^h u^n e^{-i u}du = -i +i \sum_{k = 0}^n\frac{(ih)^k}{k!}e^{-i h} 
$$
Taking real parts of both sides and substituting back into $s$ gives
$$
s(n,h,a,b) = -\frac{2n!}{a^{n+1}}\operatorname{Im}[i^ne^{i b}]\operatorname{Im}\left[\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(ih)^k}{k!}e^{-i h}\right].
$$
Unfortunately there's not a nice closed form for that sum. The closest would be $\Gamma(n+1, ih)/n!$, where $\Gamma$ is the incomplete gamma function. This gives an expression for $s(n,h,a,b)$ as
$$
s(n,h,a,b) = -\frac{2}{a^{n+1}}\operatorname{Im}[i^ne^{i b}] \operatorname{Im}[\Gamma(n+1,ih)],
$$
but it's up to you whether the imaginary part of the complex incomplete gamma function is a closed enough form.

Answer (score 0):

For this integral we can utilize the property that
$$\int_{-a}^a{f(x)dx}=\int_{-a}^a{f(-x)dx}$$

Let $$S(n,h,a,b)=I$$

Case 1: n is odd

$$I=\int_{-h}^h {x^n\: \sin(ax+b)dx}$$

Also
$$I=\int_{-h}^h {-x^n\: \sin(-ax+b)dx}$$

Adding the above equations yields
$$2I=\int_{-h}^h {x^n\: (\sin(ax+b)-\sin(-ax+b))dx}$$

Now we utilize the property that
$$\sin(A)-\sin(B)=2 \sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)  \cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)$$

Thus
$$2I=\int_{-h}^h {x^n\: 2\cos(b) \sin(ax)dx}$$

or

$$I=\cos(b)\int_{-h}^h {x^n\: \sin(ax)dx}$$

This integral does not have a closed form

(It can be represented in terms of hyper-geometric function or

incomplete gamma function)$$$$

Case 2: n is even

$$I=\int_{-h}^h {x^n\: \sin(ax+b)dx}$$

Also
$$I=\int_{-h}^h {x^n\: \sin(-ax+b)dx}$$

Adding the above equations yields
$$2I=\int_{-h}^h {x^n\: (\sin(ax+b)+\sin(-ax+b))dx}$$

Now we utilize the property that
$$\sin(A)+\sin(B)=2 \sin\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)  \cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)$$

Thus
$$2I=\int_{-h}^h {x^n\: 2\sin(a) \cos(ax)dx}$$

or

$$I=\sin(b)\int_{-h}^h {x^n\: \cos(ax)dx}$$

This integral also does not have a closed form

(It can be also be represented in terms of hyper-geometric function

or incomplete gamma function)